# Multiple property filtering of data in array of object

Tags: ecmascript-6

I've a JSON object as below:

```
let data = [{"grade":"A","batch":"night", "rating":5}, {"grade":"B", "batch":"morning", "rating":6},
{"grade":"C", "batch":"night", "rating":7},
{"grade":"A", "batch":"morning", "rating":8}]
```

I want to filter json on two properties of object named "grade" and "batch"

How can I do this in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample code. you can add the filters object whichever data you want to filter and run the code. The result will be displayed in the console of the window.

You can try running the code snippet for output

```js
function multiFilter(array, filters){
    const filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
    // filters all elements passing the criteria
    return array.filter((item) => {
        // dynamically validate all filter criteria
        return filterKeys.every(key => !!~filters[key].indexOf(item[key]));
    });
}

let data = [{"grade":"A","batch":"night", "rating":5}, {"grade":"B", "batch":"morning", "rating":6},
{"grade":"C", "batch":"night", "rating":7},
{"grade":"A", "batch":"morning", "rating":8}]
    
let filters = {
    "grade" : ["A", "B"],
    "batch" : ["morning"]
};


let  filtered = multiFilter(data, filters);

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for!